# Webpage Resize Autofit HTML Simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I just got done making my first JQuery project which is a simple full width slider. (Getting back to HTML & CSS & im currently working in C#)

Here is the issue; I dont want to be able to scroll on the page I want it to be autofit to the webpage.

Lets say I open the webpage right now, I want resize it how ever I want its responsive & its working like a charm. but you can still scroll down.
(Feel free to try it yourself with my code)

I remember this being really simple to fix but for some reason I cant remember how I did it back in the day. I'm pretty sure I will have to change something with the height; it in the CSS file or inside the body of the HTML source.

Here is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z8vqp7fe/)

My CSS file is completly empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Full Width Responsive Image Slider</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
body {font-family: Sans-Serif;}
img {max-width: 100%;}
.cycle-slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.cycle-prev, .cycle-next {
    font-size: 200;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -16px;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.cycle-prev {left: 10%;}
.cycle-next{right: 10%;}


.cycle-pager{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    position: top;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.cycle-pager span {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.cycle-pager .cycle-pager-active {background: #FFF;}

  </style>
</head>



<body>

<div class="container">

<!-- Full Width Responsive Slider -->

  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <span class="cycle-prev">&#9001;</span>
    <span class="cycle-next">&#9002;</span>
    <span class="cycle-pager"></span>
    <img src="images/Untitled.png">
    <img src="images/wp.png">
    <img src="images/wp2.png">
  </div>

<!-- Full Width Responsive Slider -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: `* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html,
body,
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
}
`

Comment: Still scrollable, added that into my css file

Comment: The problem is we can't really execute your code and debug...Can you provide Fiddle ?

Comment: I would love to! I just dont know how to use fiddle.

Comment: At least provide absolute path for your images..

Comment: it is in the code above. other I this is it.
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Development\Full WIdth Slider Varga\images

Comment: How will I get `images/Untitled.png` ?

Comment: If you create the folder on your desktop and add a folder called images & then add a image with the PNG format with the name of Untitled into that folder it should work fine im pretty sure.

Comment: Do you really want me to put so much efforts for you ? You gotta be kidding me. Anyways I do not find `cycle2` initialization in your code. Refer documentation of the same..

Comment: I am sorry, I would upload a rar file somewhere if you would like me too but thats also a bit off but I wouldnt mind, Do you know any other way I could provide you with the files needed?

Comment: as far as im concerned im pretty sure that I would need some CSS & JavaScript added because I want it stretched Horizontally & vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.

```
html,body,img {padding: 0; margin: 0;height:100%;width:100%}
body {font-family: Sans-Serif;}

.container{height:100%;width:100%;overflow: hidden;}
.cycle-slideshow {
    height: 100%;
```

where

```
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
body {font-family: Sans-Serif;}
img {max-width: 100%;}
.cycle-slideshow {
```

and if you want to change the size, just change .container

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm for the horizontall part, now I will go & try to find a solution for the vertical part thanks again!

Comment: Tested it and his suggestion seems to work just fine for full width and height of the viewport

Comment: Yeah I forgot to say I mentioned to solve it! Thanks for all the help!